# Creating a dyno using Heroku Platform API

Tags: heroku

I tried sending a POST request to https://api.heroku.com/apps/(my-app-id)/dynos with these parameters:

```
Headers: 
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer (my-api-token)",
    "Accept": "application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3"

Body: 
    command: 'node index.js',
    attach: true,
    force_no_tty: null,
    size: 'Free',
    type: 'run',
    time_to_live: 3600
```

After sending request this was in my heroku application console:

```
2019-10-29T16:53:56.305308+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `node index.js` by user (my-email)
2019-10-29T16:54:00.720264+00:00 heroku[run.1010]: State changed from starting to up
```

index.js never started and no new messages appeared. After 30 seconds i got a two new messages in console:

```
2019-10-29T16:54:30.482189+00:00 heroku[run.1010]: Process exited with status 128
2019-10-29T16:54:30.513621+00:00 heroku[run.1010]: State changed from up to complete
```

How can I create dyno correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installed `heroku-client` node package and... It worked!

Still don't understand why **my** code didn't work. ;(